# Set Parameters Report exception C#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, report

I've a report(.rdlc .NetFramework 4.0) that takes values from a dataset table.This table is generated with a TableAdpterconnection from a Stored Procedure in my sql server database.
All works,but when i added a new value in the stored procedure and added in the DataTable i've this exception error:

"local report processing exception"

this happen after the "report.SetParameters"

How can i resolve this?

(PS: The report is a LOCALREPORT)

Comment: What is the report framework here?

Comment: Rdlc Visual Studio 2012

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
this.reportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportPath = "Project.Reports.Report.rdlc";
```

To:

```
this.reportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportEmbeddedResource = "Project.Reports.Report.rdlc";
```